# Access serial port on android 5.0 6.0

Tags: android, serial-port, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to access Android serial ports by using [android-serialport-api](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-serialport-api/), it works fun on Android 4.0. But when comes to Android 5.0 and Android 6.0, it crashed because it can't find any serial port device, the code like this:

```
    File dev = new File("/dev"); 
    File[] files = dev.listFiles(); //Error on 5.0 + devices, returns a null object
```

It seems to be a permissions problem!

My android ROM development team want to solve this problem recently, they tried to give the app the permissions of devices, and `dev.listFiles()` can truely return the devices list including serial ports, but the serial port still can not access.

so, does anyone encounter the same problem? And how to modify the android source code to solve this problem?

Comment: I also tried to change the serial port device read/write permissions to 777 from adb, or use the platform key to sign the app that make the app become a system app,  but still can't access the serial port.

Comment: have you solved this issue?